tocloft breaks fancyhdr custom page number in TOC
I am trying to customize the page number format using the fancyhdr package. I am also using custom section numbering which resulted in text overlapping in the TOC, so I am using tocloft to fix that as suggested in this question.
My issue is that when I try to use a combination of tocloft and fancyhdr, it reverts the changes of the page number on the TOC back to default only on the first page of the TOC. In the example that I provide, I noticed that after the first page of the TOC, the formatted page numbering resumes.
I want the custom page numbering to remain consistent throughout the entire TOC. I do not care about the page numbering format on the title page.
\documentclass{article}

% Packages
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % for customizing header and footers
\usepackage{xcolor} % to enable color
\usepackage{tocloft} % for styling table of contents
\usepackage{pgffor} % for loops in LaTeX
\usepackage{lipsum} 

% Section numbering conventions
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}         % I, II, III...
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}   % 1, 2, 3...
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}.} % A, B, C...

% Title and author information
\title{Testing}
\author{Witt}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage

% To make the page numbers on the right and blue
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove the header line

% This is so the Roman numbers wont clip into the section titles
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{20pt}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

% Generate example sections
\foreach \i in {1,...,20} {
    \section{Section \i}
     \lipsum[1-3]
     \subsection{Subsection \i}
     \lipsum[1-2]
}

\end{document}



add \fancypagestyle{plain}{}, see the fancyhdr documentation.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you, this works!

@UlrikeFischer provided this solution.
Adding \fancypagestyle{plain}{} the line before \pagestyle{fancy} fixed the error.

Welcome to TeX.SE!
